Does "delete and decline" in Outlook on the web (OWA) send an email to the meeting organizer?
Does "delete and decline"  in Outlook on the web (OWA) send an email to the meeting organizer?


Delete and decline
Are you sure you want to delete and decline this event?
Delete and decline / Cancel



Does "delete and decline" in Outlook on the web (OWA) send an email to the meeting organizer?

"delete and decline" in Outlook on the web (OWA) doesn't send an email to the meeting organizer.
